# Bing maps with ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to run the example from "https://github.com/Microsoft/Bing-Maps-Fleet-Tracker/blob/master/MobileClient/README.md" on ionic 3. I can see the registration page but getting an error when clicking scan button: "Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: cordova is not defined
ReferenceError: cordova is not defined" and when clicking dismiss button: “self.parentView.context.dismiss is not a function”. Think I’ve completed due setup of git, nodejs and ionic(cordova). Anybody could give me an idea, please? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running it on a device/emulator?

Cordova is only enabled when the app is run on a device or an emulator. It won't work in the browser with "ionic serve".

However, some plugins work in the browser. For that you've to use the following command:

`ionic cordova run browser`

Or you can just run it on your device

`ionic cordova run android`